# if .bash_profile usually source .bashrc any way, why not just use .bashrc?

Tags: bash

it seems that we will put

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in our .bash_profile anyway.  So why not just use one file, say .bashrc ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because there may be things you only want to do once per login (so in `.bash_profile`) rather than every time an xterm or the like opens (as per `.bashrc`), for example asking the user for a passphrase to decrypt and load SSH keys into an ssh agent, etc etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can put some things in `.bash_profile` that are not appropriate for a shell instance that is not a terminal. For example, if you ran an external command from your editor through the shell - the shell instance would source `.bashrc` but not `.bash_profile`. For example, I might put `alias ls=ls -F` in my profile, but you wouldn't want that alias applied for just any instance of the shell, just ones you would interact with.

Comment: Just want to note that the RC file is read on interactive shells only (unless forced or different startup mode, like POSIX mode or sh).